# Js fetch post to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, fetch

**В чём моя ошибка?**

[image: js]
[image: php]

Почему-то php не видит Post, хотя запрос отправлен( проверено), что я делаю не так?

Comment: если в body у вас не пары ключ значения, а просто данные, то получать его придется через `php://input`. В вашем случае в body следует вписать объект `{ type: idType}`, и далее открыв вкладу Сеть в браузере убедиться, что в запросе данные отправляются.

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, body должен принимать объект

`body:{type:idType}`

Comment: Да, изначально так и делал, но всё равно не получал нужный в php Post ключ..
Поэтому ща начал уже переделывать и тестить.
Крч, с вашим вариантом тоже не работало

Comment: а если так body:JSON.stringify({type:idType})

Comment: Запрос - то отправляется, но в php :
$_POST['type'] = null

Comment: Странно что `body:JSON.stringify({type:idType})`. Я так понимаю массив $_POST вообще пустой?